# Create own web url extension

Tags: php, html, url, web

I have seen a website that uses file name extensions that are different from those elsewhere; I couldn't find any information about the file extensions elsewhere so I am asking here. Here is an example URL:

```
https://cs.bpjsketenagakerjaan.go.id/rekrutmen/register.bpjs
```

The extension is `*.bpjs` (usually it is `php`, `html` or hidden isn't it?)

Is this a custom extension? How could I create these `.bpjs` files on a website myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: by using `.htaccess`

Comment: You would set up your server to interpret files with a .bpjs suffix as HTML (or whatever type of file it was).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `bpjs` refer to special file extension but as Damon.s say's you can use `.htaccess` to rewrite your files extensions, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [L]
```

Change `*.php` to `*.html`

Or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.bpjs [L]
```

Change `*.php` to `*.bpjs`

But this is just mask (rewrite) for your file extension.

Comment: Thanks for answer, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

To use custom extensions, you'll need to add a MIME type to your server (configurable in your server software). That MIME type will map a file extension to a specific HTTP content type. For example, a file extension of **.bpjs** could return a content type of `Content-Type: text/html` which the browser would process as a standard HTML document.

Also, depending on your needs, you'd need to also instruct your server to process it with your server-side framework (PHP, ASP.NET, etc.) via configuration. For example, in IIS this could be done via the Mappings setting. The configuration of this differs if you're using Apache, IIS, or other servers.